# Azure Device Provisioning - Setting Device Twin property

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-suite, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I want to use the device provisioning in Azure for my devices.

I'm using the Azure IoT SDK (Java).

I would like to create a new device that have some specific properties inside the JSON of the device twin.
I want to see my new device in Azure portal with a custom JSON for the device twin.

In the **ProvisioningTpmSample** class ([Link GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/master/provisioning/provisioning-samples/provisioning-tpm-sample/src/main/java/samples/com/microsoft/azure/sdk/iot/ProvisioningTpmSample.java)). There is this piece of code:

```
try
{
    deviceClient = DeviceClient.createFromSecurityProvider(iotHubUri, deviceId, securityClientTPMEmulator, IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT);
    deviceClient.open();
    Message messageToSendFromDeviceToHub =  new Message("Whatever message you would like to send");

    System.out.println("Sending message from device to IoT Hub...");
    deviceClient.sendEventAsync(messageToSendFromDeviceToHub, new IotHubEventCallbackImpl(), null);
}
```

I find the method setProperty for the Message. It's like

```
messageToSendFromDeviceToHub.setProperty("test", "test");
```

Is it possible to defined the *desired* and *required* properties of the device twin by this **setProperty** method?

Thanks a lot

Comment: the device twins and telemetry data message (D2C messages) are different entities. The setProperty method can be used only for populating a property of the telemetry data message (D2C message).

Comment: @RomanKiss you are right thanks a lot!. Anywhere, I find an 'Initial Twin Device' section in Device Service Provisioning area where you can set the device twin JSON.